# Standardization breaks my Lasso regression model

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn, lasso, standardization

I'm trying to apply a Lasso regression model on some data (the ultimate goal is to perform feature selection) using sklearn.

When the data features are not standardized, the resulting test score is around 0.90. However, when i standardize the features (using StandardScaler) something breaks for a reason and the test score is 0. 
This is unsatisfactory, as from my understanding standardization is required in case of Lasso. I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

Without standardization:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

lasso = Lasso()
lasso.fit(X,Ri)
train_score = lasso.score(X,Ri) 
# results in a test score of 0.93 and 109 coefficients/features used
```

Including standardization:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

stand_scaler = StandardScaler()
x = X.values #returns np array
x_scaled = stand_scaler.fit_transform(x)
lasso = Lasso()
lasso.fit(x_scaled,Ri)
train_score = lasso.score(x_scaled,Ri) 
# results in a test score of 0 and 0 coefficients/features used
```

Comment: Are you throwing an error when running on the standardized data set?  If so, can you post it here?  This kind of thing normally happens when you're trying to standardize a label, etc.

Comment: Is "Ri" the lasso parameter? I would not expect identical performance after standardization but using the lasso parameter from the standardized data.

Comment: What do the various Python functions actually do? I don't use Python at all. But it seems like you did something wrong in the code. Standardizing should make the lasso not fit any variables at all where it previously fit a lot.